# Trying to use javascript to fill a tag of button class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

edit 3: I'm just going to kind of start over.

I can't post two links but the theme I'm using is Red Ink from themeforest and the page I'm working on is the portfolio page if you want to google it.

When you click one of the portfolio items like "True Gangsters" all the info is pulled from the div and plugged into a previous section for formatting.

All I want to do is add a button to these portfolio items and be able to pull the link from the div and have it formatted into a button.

in the jsfiddle I included the formatted div and the "true gangsters" section that the formatted div gets its info from.

I also included all of the portfolio part javascript but I'm pretty sure this is the important part:

```js
//Update text info
     function updateText(current) {

       var title = current.attr('data-title');
       var desc = current.attr('data-description');
       var date = current.attr('data-date');

       controls.find('h2').html(title);
       controls.find('p').html(desc);
       controls.find('.date .day').html(date.split(',')[0]);
       controls.find('.date .month').html(date.split(',')[1]);
       controls.find('.date .year').html(date.split(',')[2]);

     } //End Update text info
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vbgfsgg7/)

This is proving to be more complicated than I thought it would be.

---

---

**Old section, ignore me:**

So I'm trying to use javascript to get a chunk of code from another part of the webpage and then insert it into a different part to create a link on

```
<div class="button"></div>


<div class="getVid"
   data-epdLink="CdDDY5nVA3A"
>
```

so I want to get the piece of code from the getVid div and put it into the button div as a link.

so I have this bit of JavaScript:

```
var endLink = current.attr('data-epdLink');

var fullLink = '<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + endLink +'">"Click for Video"</a>';

controls.find('button').html(fullLink)
```

It doesn't seem to work. I've used this type of thing before to insert headers and text but I'm thinking there's something different I've got to do to insert code.

Any ideas?

Here's a link to fiddle if that helps: [JSFiddle][3]

**Edit**

Forgot to mention that there will be multiple getVid classes so it depends on which one I have open and the data-epdLink will be different for each.

**Edit 2**

Ok so in my new jsfiddle you can see that all of the formatting is in the top part of the html labeled vid item formatting. The next two items each labeled vid item pull info from the vid formatting section using javascript. This code is from a template so I'm not entirely sure what's going on but I included the javascript that changes the image on each vid item section because I think I could change the button link using something along those lines. You can see the button div right after both of the tables in the vid formatting section.

New jsfiddle here: [new js fiddle][4]

edit 3: I'm just going to kind of start over. 
First off here's the template I'm using [Red Ink Template][1]

When you click one of the portfolio items like "True Gangsters" all the info is pulled from the div and plugged into a previous section for formatting.

All I want to do is add a button to these portfolio items and be able to pull the link from the div and have it formatted into a button.

This is proving to be more complicated than I thought it would be.

Comment: current or endLink are not what you think, it works otherwise: https://jsfiddle.net/23g5egLo/

Comment: This question has now been re-asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38576425/one-button-mulitple-links-link-changes-depending-on-which-div-is-open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to close your `.getVid` div. It is a best practice to use [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method to access `data-` attributes:

```
var endLink = current.data('epdlink');

var fullLink = '<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + endLink +'">"Click for Video"</a>';

controls.filter('.button').html(fullLink);
```

You will get it as lowercase, e.g. `edplink`. I believe that your variable `controls` is a collection of html elements, so whenever you have to search in a pre-selected collection use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5c5zmgr9/5/)

Comment: This works but is there a way to target the current getVid div that I'm on considering I'll have multiple getVid divs each with a different data-epdLink?

Comment: @S.Marie try adding more information and more code on your question.

Comment: I added some more info if you have time to take a look

Comment: @S.Marie I looked into your fiddle, but there is too much code I can't understand w/o debugging, and in fact I could not understand exactly what you described in your 2nd edit...

Comment: @S.Marie can you isolate your problem in the fiddle ? To make it short..

Comment: I rewrote my question if you want to give it another go

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery `.append()`

Use `.data()` instead of `.attr()`
**HTML**

```
<div class="button"></div>


<div class="getVid"
  data-epdLink="CdDDY5nVA3A"
>
```

**JS**

```
var endLink = $('.getVid').data('epdlink');

var fullLink = '<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + endLink +'">"Click for Video"</a>';

$('.button').append(fullLink)
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/5c5zmgr9/1/)

In case you have multiple divs

```
$('.getVid').each(function(i, v){
    var endLink = $(v).data('epdlink');
    var fullLink = '<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + endLink +'">"Click for Video"</a>';
$(v).prev('.button').append(fullLink)
})
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5c5zmgr9/6/)**

Comment: This works, thank you! Just one problem, I forgot to mention that I'll have multipled getVid divs. Is there any way to do this using current.attr ?

Comment: @S.Marie Can you use seperate Ids. Or id that you want to apply this to all the divs

Comment: I could use seperate Ids. would I just make a seperate JS for each Id replacing .getVid with #newID?

Comment: @S.Marie No need, there is a way around. If you want to do this with all the divs, I will edit the code shortly

Comment: That would be awesome

Comment: @S.Marie I edited my code for multiple divs. Have a look at it

Comment: sorry, this is very close but it won't work. I need the code to each link to the same button instead of creating new buttons. I updated my question, I should have been more clear the first time.Thanks though!

Comment: @S.Marie How do you decide which link to add to button. Its very difficult to understand what has been going around in your code

Comment: I rewrote my question to try and make things easier to understand